# How to count array level "deep" number and count total elements on each level of an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to do recursive array in function to get all level number and the total element counts on each level for a multi-dimensional array.

I need help to achieve this goal I'm stack and can't come up of good solution.

My data

```
$tree = array(
        'room1' => array(
                'room5',
                'room6'
            ),
        'room2' => array(
                'room5',
                'room6'
            ),
        'room3' => array(
                'room7' => array(
                        'room12' => array(
                                'room14',
                                'room15'
                            ),
                        'room13'
                    ),
            ),
        'room4' => array(
                'room8',
                'room9',
                'room10',
                'room11'
            )
);
```

Desired Result

```
Array(
    'level1' => 4,
    'level2' => 9,
    'level3' => 2,
    'level4' => 2
)
```

My Code

```
function treeOut($tree)
{
    $markup = '';
    $count = 0;
    foreach($tree as $branch => $twig)
    {
        $count++;
        ((is_array($twig)) ? treeOut($twig,$count) : $count++;
    }
    return $count

}

echo treeOut($tree);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive count elements of multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36323069/recursive-count-elements-of-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 3):

As 1st try

```
function treeOut($tree, $level=0, $counts=[])
{
  if(! isset($counts[$level])) $counts[$level] = 0; 
  foreach($tree as $branch => $twig)
    {
        $counts[$level]++;
        if(is_array($twig)) {
          $counts = treeOut($twig, $level+1, $counts);
          }
    }
    return $counts;
}

print_r(treeOut($tree));
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/945212)

Comment: hi @splash58! Than you! This is what Im looking for that gives me headache. Thank you very much!

Comment: @moreishi Please accept this answer since it works! Thank you splash58